# Why did the werewolf kill an "innocent" victim?

Tags: plot-explanation, silver-bullet

In [*Silver Bullet*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090021/), the werewolf apparently only kills individuals who are leading a sinful life or anyone who threatens [him](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Lester_Lowe):

**SPOILER ALERT**

> Reverend Lester Lowe is a werewolf that has been terrorizing the town
>   of Tanker's Mill although it is unknown how he became a werewolf.
>   However, Lester does not see his werewolf transformation as a curse
>   but a bliss given to him by the almighty to punish people who are
>   evil, immoral and corrupt. This is not to say he is above killing
>   innocent people: he has killed innocents who were close to discovering
>   his secret even though they committed no bad deeds.

The werewolf kills the following [people](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090021/faq?ref_=tt_faq_sm):

- Arnie Westrum - An alcoholic railroad worker
- Stella Randolph - An unwed pregnant woman who was having an affair with a married man and had just taken sleeping pills to commit suicide
- Milt Sturmfuller - The abusive Father of Marty's girlfriend
- Andy Fairton - The leader of the group who went hunting the werewolf.
- Joe Haller - The sheriff who went to investigate Reverend Lowe
- Brady Kincaid - Marty's best friend

Reverend Lowe even tells Marty that he would never willingly hurt a child after he traps Marty.  He is only pursuing Marty because Marty knows his true identity and injured him and has threatened him.

> I'm very sorry about this, Marty. I don't know if you believe that or
>   not, but it's true. I would never willingly hurt a child.

However, the werewolf killed Brady Kincaid fairly early in the film.  Brady was still a child and posed no threat to the werewolf.  Marty didn't discover the identity of the werewolf until after Brady was killed.

The werewolf/Reverend Lowe thinks of himself as somewhat of a vigilante, which does not make any sense why he killed Brady

**Is it ever explained why the werewolf killed Brady Kincaid?**

Comment: Wikipedia says he was a "troublemaker"...

Comment: He was still a child, though.  And he was hardly a troublemaker in the same sense that the adults that were "sinning"

Comment: But as your spoiler says..he's not above killing innocents....but maybe?

Comment: Yeah...who were close to discovering his secret.  Brady wasn't close to discovering his secret nor did he threaten him.  That's why I included that sentence in the paragraph.

Comment: He was out past curfew, he was fascinated in the kite, why else would there be a curfew because of the wolf? He was killed on April fools day. There is also the *cover up* where you lie to someone and say you would never do something but when no one is around you do the complete opposite becuse no one actually knows your real identity and you tend to think if you do something, it wont lead back to the other me, so you do it.

Comment: @natural When does it say that he was killed on April Fool's Day?

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm trying to say the Reverend wants to believe he could never do those things. He is unable to cope with the werewolf side of him, cannot accept that he can and does hurt innocent children. Even Marty was not aware of a werewolf until he saw it, so I don't think it attacked him because he was on to him, not the first time. Also, listen to his tone. He has Marty trapped in the old bridge. He's coaxing, trying to earn his trust. It's "I would never willingly harm a child...now take my hand..." That's not the "good guy" in the bridge with Marty. That's the "wolf", the other side, trying to lure him in. But yes, historically, it is believed that serial killers are werewolves, in a sense that they were born from a superstitious time where these crimes were often imagined as being committed by "beasts". The Werewolf Book is chock full of examples.
Starrett is a complicated guy. It's really difficult to sum him up easily. There's a book about him called A Stranger in the Family, but you could probably just as easily read about him online for free.

Directly to the question, I don't believe an answer is ever spelled out to Brady's death, but we know the Reverend Lowe is fond of her (again, by his tone, "Hello, Jane!") And that Brady can be a "cruel and unsympathetic" boy, a prankster who takes things too far. He may have roused Lowe's anger with the cruelty he showed Janie.

Comment: There's no direct relationship between RDS and Silver Bullet. Writers draw from real life situations, but that's not to say King was influenced by his particular story, but they have similar personality types.

Answer (score 0):

I think Brady was victim to the purely wolf side. The priest says he would never willingly hurt a child. So in a sense, the monster was out of control beyond the Reverend. It's simply a case of predator killing prey. Also, Marty knows nothing of his true identity when he is first attacked on the bridge while playing with the fireworks, it isn't until the Rev shows up with the same wound as the wolf that Marty and his sister put it together.